# SQL Server 2008: Update columns if its a null

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 100 columns in my table and I want to update only columns that have NULL value.

I am comparing master table columns with temp table and trying to update master table column value with temp table column value.

Please help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance

Comment: attach sample table and desired output

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Update t1
set field1 = coalesce(t1.field1, 'test')
  , field2 = coalesce(t1.field2, t1.field1)
  , field3 = coalesce(t1.field3, t2.field1)
  , field4 = coalesce(t1.field4, t2.field1, t2.field3)

FROM table1 t1
join table2 t2
 on t1.someid = t2.someId
```

I have given you three examples of differnt ways you might update if the field is null. The first shows how to set it to a text value, the second how to set it to another field in the same table and third is the one where you get the value from a different table. The forth shows what to do if the value you are setting it to is also nul and thus want to use still another value in its place. You will need to write a coalesce update for each of the 100 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE B SET B.value = T.value
FROM
tblMaster B 
   INNER JOIN tblTemp T ON B.ID = T.ID
WHERE B.value IS NULL
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

The following should update a row in the master table with either its previous value (if it is not `null`) or the value from the temp table if the value of the master table is `null`.

This requires that master and temp table can be joined on a key field named `Key` in my case.

```
UPDATE m
SET
  m.field1 = ISNULL(m.field1, t.field1), 
  ...
FROM
  MasterTable m
  INNER JOIN TempTable t ON t.Key = m.Key
```